# Trying to implement an extremely simple toy version of std::vector and hitting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS which I don't understand

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++, and was trying to implement a simple version of std::vector when I hit the bug I mention in the title. The following code sometimes triggers a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a line which I mark with a comment on the code snippet below, and I am not sure why. Anyone have any suggestions? I thought that `new` just malloc'd memory, having trouble understanding how that could fail. Thanks!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T, int init_size = 1>
struct Vector
{
    T* store = new T[1];
    size_t length = init_size;
    size_t size = init_size;
    void append(T value)
    {
        length++;
        if (length > size)
        {
            printf("Reallocated store\n");
            size_t new_size = size * 2;
            T* newStore = new T[size];  // Sometimes gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS
            memcpy(newStore, store, size * sizeof(size_t));
            delete[] store;
            store = newStore;
            size = new_size;
        }
        store[length - 1] = value;
        
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Vector<int> vector;
    for(int i=0; i<20; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j<vector.length; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << vector.store[j] << "-";
        }
        printf("\n");
        vector.append(i);
    }
    
}
```

Edit: Ended up fixing it thanks to PaulMcKenzie's reply. Still, not sure why the exception popped up at `T* newStore = new T[size]` instead of at `store[length - 1] = value;` which is where I am actually accessing unallocated memory. Any ideas?

Comment: `memcpy(newStore, store, size * sizeof(size_t));` -- No, use `std::copy`.  Your class fails miserably if it were a `Vector<std::string>`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

The first and foremost is this one:

```
size_t new_size = size * 2;
T* newStore = new T[size];  // <------ Error
```

You failed to use `new_size` when you used `new[]`.  The code should be:

```
size_t new_size = size * 2;
T* newStore = new T[new_size];
```

---

The second issue is that you should use `std::copy` to copy the elements, not `memcpy`.  The `memcpy` will fail to work on objects that are non trivially-copyable, such as `std::string`:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::copy(store, store + size, newStore);
```

---

The last item is that your class does not have a user-defined copy constructor, destructor, and assignment operator, thus making `Vector` have incorrect copy semantics.

I'm assuming this last item exists only due to you not having your class completed.  But I advise that you complete these copy functions before adding any more functionality.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for such a thorough answer! That was exactly it, I was using `size` instead of `new_size`! Regarding the other comments, you are absolutely right, I was just starting to write the class when the error popped up. One question though, why is the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` being marked by my debugger as happening on the line containing the `new` instruction, and not on the line where I assigned a value to unallocated memory later, which I guess is where the error is actually happening.